# Substraction in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

my problem is as follows. I am currently generating a tax receipt for some orders (not all) in my woocommerce. but the customer would like for 3 of the 4 products to be priced at €60. Outside in the shop it is for example 110.
Can we make a subtraction on certain product id when the user generates his receipt?
here is part of my calculation function.
Thanks for help ^^

```
add_action( 'init', 'silva_add_endpoint' );
function silva_add_endpoint() {
 
    // WP_Rewrite is my Achilles' heel, so please do not ask me for detailed explanation
    add_rewrite_endpoint( 'tax-receipt', EP_PAGES );
 
}
/*
 * Part 3. Content for the new page in My Account, woocommerce_account_{ENDPOINT NAME}_endpoint
 */
add_action( 'woocommerce_account_tax-receipt_endpoint', 'silva_my_account_endpoint_content' );
function silva_my_account_endpoint_content() {
 
    // GET CURR USER
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    if ( 0 == $current_user->ID ) return;
   
    // GET USER ORDERS (COMPLETED + PROCESSING)
    $customer_orders = get_posts( array(
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'meta_key'    => '_customer_user',
        'meta_value'  => $current_user->ID,
        'post_type'   => wc_get_order_types(),
        'post_status' => array_keys( wc_get_is_paid_statuses() ),
    ) );
   
    // LOOP THROUGH ORDERS AND GET PRODUCT IDS
    if ( ! $customer_orders ) return;
    $product_ids = array();
    ?>
        <div class="donate">
            <h4>Reçu fiscal</h4>
            <h5>Par année</h5>
            <h6 style="font-weight:bold;"><span style="color:red;">Attention :</span> si vous avez réglé votre don et/ou votre adhésion avec différents moyens de paiement,  vous devez télécharger vos reçus fiscaux individuellement pour chaque transaction en cliquant sur le bouton «Télécharger» dans la colonne «Téléchargement» ci-dessous.</h6>
            <h6>2021 <a href="https://union-rationaliste.org/year-download-pdf/?id=2021" style="border: solid 1px; padding: 7px 10px; margin-left: 22px;">Télécharger le reçu de l'année complète</a></h6>
        <table>
            <th>Numéro de reçu</th>
            <th>Prénom</th>
            <th>Nom de famille</th>
            <th>E-mail</th>
            <th>Téléphoner</th>
            <th>Code postal</th>
            <th>Téléchargement</th>
            <?php
                foreach ( $customer_orders as $customer_order ) {
                    
        $order = wc_get_order( $customer_order->ID );
        $year = explode('-',$order->get_date_created());
        if($year[0]=='2021'){
            $items = $order->get_items();
        foreach ( $items as $item ) {
            //print_r($customer_order);
            
            $product_id = $item->get_product_id();
            $product_ids[] = $product_id;
            if(in_array(1708, $product_ids) || in_array(1724, $product_ids) || in_array(1742, $product_ids) || in_array(1758, $product_ids) || in_array(9463, $product_ids)){
                ?>
                <tr>
                    <td>#<?php echo $order->id; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $order->get_billing_first_name(); ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $order->get_billing_last_name(); ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $order->get_billing_email(); ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $order->get_billing_phone(); ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $order->get_billing_postcode(); ?></td>
                    <td><a href="https://union-rationaliste.org/download-pdf/?id=<?php echo $order->id; ?>">Télécharger</a></td>
                </tr>
                <?php
                //print_r($order);
            }
        }
        }
    }
            ?>
```

Comment: This looks like part of a function, not the whole thing. Can you add more details?

Comment: I have update my function if you want